# Optimization of Djikstra-like algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dijkstra

I tried to design a simple algorithm to visit a graph using a Dijkstra-like algorithm, but when the graph is VERY large (more than 75000 nodes) it seems to be not optimized.

This is my code

```
class lamp {

    int id;
    bool visited = false;
    list<lamp*> connected;
    int distance = INT_MAX;

public:
    void setVisited() {
        visited = true;
    }

    bool isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    void addCOnnected(lamp* l) {
        connected.push_back(l);
    }

    list<lamp*> getConnected() {
        return connected;
    }

    void resetVisited() {
        visited = false;
    }

    void setId(int i) {
        id = i;
    }

    void setDistance(int d) {
        distance = distance < d ? distance : d;
    }

    int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

};

void resetVisited(lamp* l, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l[i].resetVisited();
    }
}

void evaluateDistance(lamp& l) {

    queue<lamp*> lampQueue;
    lampQueue.push(&l);
    l.setDistance(1);

    while (lampQueue.size() > 0) {

        lamp* current = lampQueue.front();
        lampQueue.pop();
        int currentDistance = current->getDistance();

        for (lamp* conn : current->getConnected()) {
            if (!(conn->isVisited())) {
                lampQueue.push(conn);
                conn->setVisited();
                conn->setDistance(currentDistance + 1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The strange setDistance is due to the fact that the evaluation of the distance of any lamp is perfomed multiple times starting from different lamps and the lowest is retained in each cycle.

Comment: This looks like it should have complexity O(number of edges).  How many edges are in the graph?  I would expect it to be able to cope with perhaps 20 million per second.  If the performance is much lower, I would recommend using a profiler to check that time is not being spent in some unexpected place (e.g. memory management, copying data structures, pushing to the end of a list)

Comment: What do you mean by not optimizing? as the number of nodes grows the sum of distances should fall greatly at the start and then nearly not at the end of the run?

Comment: In a competition It seems taking too much time on a single test. I'll try to get a hint on the number of edges/vertices involved.